# How to remove the newline characters from each word in a list?

Tags: python, string, newline

How can I remove the first two characters of a word that is in a list?

For example, I have the following list:

```
List = ['\ nNew', '\ nIndustrial', '\ nColombia']
```

How can I remove the `'\ n'` from each word?

Comment: Hi Maria! What is the language you are using? And have you tried anything? If you did, can you post your code and tell us the errors you found?

Comment: Also, it seems either you need to remove one character (which would be "new line" - `\n`), or three chars (which would be the slash, the space and "n"). Am I right?

Comment: fyi: it is actually the first 3 characters. '\', ' ', & 'n'. the space is a character.

Comment: i am working with Python. This is the code i have but it isnt working, i am still getting the same list with the '\n'. CODE :                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 for item in newstring:
    result = newstring.replace("\n", "")

result

Comment: I have also tried this one:                                                                                                                result = newstring.rstrip('\n' or '\\n')

result

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado yes, you are right!

Answer (score 0):

```py
l = ['\ nNew', '\ nIndustrial', '\ nColombia']
clean_list = [ w[3:] for w in l ]
```

Basically two things here :

- Used list comprehension to create a new list
- Used string slicing to remove the first three characters

Answer (score -1):

Something simple like

```
for (String str : list) {
    str.replace("\n", "");
}
```

would work if this is in Java.
Or even `list.forEach(str -> str.replace("\n", ""));`.

Comment: The question has been tagged with python, and OP [confirms in comment that they are "*working in Python*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69773973/how-to-remove-the-newline-characters-from-each-word-in-a-list/69774054#comment123334252_69773973).